# WORDPRESS : Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in td_block.php

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've just started using XAMP (PHP v. 7.2.7). 
When I uploaded a theme and installed the demo, I've got the error message :

> Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\IonMag\includes\wp_booster\td_block.php on line 365**

Here is what's on the line 365:

```
if ($this->td_query->found_posts - $offset > $limit) {$this->block_uid . '" data-td_block_id="' . $this->block_uid . '"><i class="td-icon-font td-icon-menu-right"></i></a>';
```

Thank you in advance guys !

Comment: `Line 365` but you show us `356`, okaaay.

Comment: thank you for your notice, I've updated it now

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in PHP 7.1, a Warning will be emitted if a non-numeric value is encountered. See this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.other-changes.php)

Here is the relevant portion that pertains to the Warning notice you are getting:

> New E_WARNING and E_NOTICE errors have been introduced when invalid
>   strings are coerced using operators expecting numbers or their
>   assignment equivalents. An E_NOTICE is emitted when the string begins
>   with a numeric value but contains trailing non-numeric characters, and
>   an E_WARNING is emitted when the string does not contain a numeric
>   value.

```html
<?php    
$block_id = $this->block_uid;

elseif (is_numeric($block_id)) {
  $buffy .= '<a href="#"  class="td-ajax-next-page" id="next-page-' . $block_id . '" data-td_block_id="' . $block_id . '"><i class="td-icon-font td-icon-menu-right"></i></a>';
} else {
  // do some error handling...
}
?>
```

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake when sharing the error code. I updated it